# Loading state button in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap 3. Can't figure out how to activate the loading state button function. My code below is from the documents on [getboostrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com).

```
<button type="button" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
  Loading state
</button>
```

Dropdowns works fine so I guess the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You need to detect the click from js side, your HTML remaining same. **Note**: this method is deprecated since v3.5.5 and removed in v4.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.button('loading');
    // simulating a timeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        $btn.button('reset');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Also, don't forget to load jQuery and Bootstrap js (based on jQuery) file in your page.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/deC37/)

[Official Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples)

Comment: Just what I needed ... tyvm!

Comment: can you please explain how do i achieve this from an ng-click instead of jquery's click, i want to do this loading thing but i am using angular and kinda new

Comment: "This feature is deprecated since v3.3.5 and has been removed in v4." (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Comment: @RoelVermeulen Thanks! Are you aware of an alternative? Using `text(...)` and disabling the button will probably work as well, as long there is no better solution.

Comment: Note that `loading` is a button state not the text displayed, if you try to amend it to something other helpful text it doesn't work! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have v4 or higher, you can do this: ‍♂️

```js
$.loading = function(btn, action){
  if(action && !btn.data('old-html')){
    btn.data('old-html', btn.html()).prop("disabled", true).html(btn.data('loading-text') || 'Loading...');
    return
  }
  if(!btn.data('old-html')) return;
  btn.prop("disabled", false).html(btn.data('old-html')).data('old-html', false);
} 

$("button, .button").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $.loading($btn, true)
    setTimeout(function () {
       $.loading($btn, false);
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button>salve</button>
<button
  data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spinn'></i> Loading..."
>salve</button>
<a href="#" class="button">salvar</a>
</html>
```