# Animated loading circle when submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have the following HTML application:

```
<html>

<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0-RC3/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        .jumbotron {
            background-color: #3cba54;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }

        .dates {
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        @media(max-width: 900px) {
            .dates {
                width: 80%;
            }
            input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                line-height: 3;
            }
        }

        .label {
            padding-right: 10px;
            width: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #383b3d;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .icon {
            font-size: 2em !important;
        }

        input {
            border-radius: 10px !important;
            border-style: solid;
        }



        body {
            color: #383b3d;
        }



        .submit {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }

        #load:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }



    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h1 class="text-center">Business trip details</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <form id="specials">

            <!-- =============================================================================================== Name of offer or amendment ================================================================== -->

            <div class="form-group">

                <label class="label1" for="title"><em>Destinations visited</em></label>

                <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Paris, Lille" name="offerName">

            </div>

            <hr>

            <!--=================================================== Date picker =========================================================================            -->

            <div class="label1 text-center"><em>Please enter the start and end date of your business trip</em></div>

            <div class="container dates">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt label icon"></i>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datepickerFrom" placeholder="Start date" name="firstDate">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container dates">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt label icon"></i>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datepickerTo" placeholder="End date" name="lastDate">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg submit" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending">Submit</button>


    </form>

    </div>

</body>

<!--==============================================================================================================================-->

<script>

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });

    // Info for saving email


    $('form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
                google.script.host.close()
            })
            .saveAsSpreadsheet(e.currentTarget);
    }); 


    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
       var $this = $(this);
            $this.button('loading');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.button('reset');
            }, 15000)
        });

</script>

</html>
```

I'm trying to create an animated loading affect when the submit button is clicked whilst the script is running. I've used this same bit of code on other apps and it has always worked but for some reason here I cannot get it to function. This is obviously the key piece of code:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
        $this.button('loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.button('reset');
        }, 15000)
    });
```

I'm sure there is something incredibly obvious I'm doing wrong here - I just cannot figure it out as it seems identical to the code I have working elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, you just didn't take the right approach, that `setTimeout` has to be removed, i adjusted your script below:

I made the following changes:

1. `$('form').on("submit")` - form will wait to be triggered by the button
2. in `withSuccessHandler` i added `$('.btn').html('Submit')` - the default text
3. you will find the content `loading` and `$("form").trigger('submit')` in the .btn click handler
4. You can safely remove the `google` object i created

   ```
      $(function() {

          $(".datepicker").datepicker({
             format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
           });

        $('form').on("submit", function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();

         var google = {
           script: {
             run: {
               withSuccessHandler: function(cb) {
                 var ggResponse = ['some', 'data'];

                 if (typeof cb === 'function') {

                   setTimeout(function() {
                     cb(ggResponse);
                   }, 3000)

                 }
                 return this;
               },
               saveAsSpreadsheet: function(element) {
                 return this;
               }
             },
             host: {
               close: function() {
                 console.log('conn to google closed')
               }
             }
           }
         };

         google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {

             $('.btn').html('Submit')

             google.script.host.close()
           })
           .saveAsSpreadsheet(e.currentTarget);
       });


       $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();

         var $this = $(this);

         $this.html($this.attr('data-loading-text'));

         $("form").trigger('submit');

       });

      });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I get jQuery loading error. It's missing https: in href.

And here is your answer: [Loading state button in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069759/loading-state-button-in-bootstrap-3)

This method is deprecated since v3.5.5 and removed in v4.
And you are using v.4.1.3.